# Show that every linear transformation $\mathbb R^{n}$ ->$\mathbb R^{m}$ transforms linear dependent vectors into linear dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let's say we have a matrix $\mathbb R^{m*n}$ which contains a zero vector and some random vectors that are linear dependent. Example matrix M:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 6 & . & .& 1 \\
    . &  3& . & .& 1 \\
    . &  6& . & .& 1 \\
    . &  4& . & .&2 \\
    0 &  5& . & .& 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
I've choose a vector $\vec x$ = [ $x_1$ . . .$x_m$]$^{T}$, So M$\vec x$ shows us this as 
 $\vec x_2$ = [ 0$x_1$ + . . .+$x_m$, 0$x_1$+3$x_2$ + . . .+$x_m$, ....  ]$^{T}$. Is this a good proof?

Comment: you have to show that the claim holds for every linear transformation, giving one example of a a matrix such that the claim holds does not prove anything

Comment: Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a Linear transformation, the question asking you to prove that $\{T(v_1),T(v_2)\}$ is a Linearly dependent subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to prove it generally, not merely provide an example showing that it may be true. Let me outline how you might approach it.

- Suppose that $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_k\in\Bbb R^n$ (where $k$ is some integer greater than $1$) such that $\{\vec v_j:1\le j\le k\}$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\Bbb R^n.$
- Suppose that $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is any linear transformation.
- Let $\vec w_j=T(\vec v_j)$ for each integer $j$ such that $1\le j\le k.$
- Now, unpack the definition of linear dependence to rewrite our first assumption, and use our second assumption to conclude that $\{\vec w_j:1\le j\le k\}$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\Bbb R^m.$